# What is this application showing a green download icon when I press ALT-TAB?

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

I have a **Dell Latitude** with **Windows 7**.

When I press **ALT-TAB** to switch applications, I always see an application that has a "**green download**" icon:

[image]

When I select it, a **little gray rectangle** appears in the upper left corner of my screen:

[image]

In Task-Manager/**Applications** this application doesn't show up, and in Task-Manager/**Processes** I can't find a process that seems to identify it.

I believe this is something from Dell, like some kind of update manager but am not sure.

**Does anyone recognize this icon, know what it is, know how to kill or deinstall it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Dell Backup Tool. Look for the icon in the system tray and right click to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Try launching [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), (Optional:  then click `File` > `Show Details for All Processes`, then bring up your grey box and click/drag the Process Explorer `Find Target` button.

[image]

Drag it to the box and see what process it belongs to.

Alternatively, hunt down the list for that icon!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can move the window as follows? If you can move it onto your screen, it'll be much easier to handle.

- Bring the window into focus using `Alt+Tab`.
- Type `Alt+Spacebar` to open the window menu (you won't see it).
- Type `m` to select the menu item "move".
- Press the down/right arrow keys, possibly repeatedly, to move the window.

You can "practice" this with another (non-maximized) window. Are you able to move the mystical window too? If yes, you can now see what it is. If not, this answer regrets to be unable to help you.